# How to avoid duplication of mysql table entries?

Tags: php, mysql

I seem to be getting duplicating table entries with using this PHP code. Every time I hit refresh, when it inserts what I have hard coded and prints previous entries (even if they values are the same).

What I want to know is how can I avoid duplication if the values are the same? I also do not want the code to duplicate entries when the page refreshes.

```
//insert data entries
mysqli_query ($con, "INSERT IGNORE INTO alarms(Title, Description, DT)
    VALUES('get', 'Agha will eat', '2013-08-05 00:15:12')");
```

This is the print function.

```
//print out data entries
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM alarms");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
    echo $row['alarmID'] . " <br> " . $row['Title'] . " <br> " . $row['Description'] . " <br> " . $row['DT'];
 }
```

Comment: To avoid page refresh inserts, use  [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `UNIQUE` constraint in your `alarm` table based on the values which you want to be unique.

Suppose that for every row, you want the `Title`, `Description` and `DT` triples to be unique. Then, add the `UNIQUE` constraint in your `alarm` table in the following way -

```
ALTER TABLE alarm ADD CONSTRAINT uc_alarm UNIQUE (Title, Description, DT)
```

If you do this, then whenever you try to insert a row whose `Title`, `Description` and `DT` matches with those of an existing rows, MySQL will generate an error and reject that insert command.

Check out [this short tutorial](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqltutorial/constraints/) for a overview of the `UNIQUE` constraint.

Comment: Do I use UNIQUE constraint on all the entries? Also, what about the DT (DATE TIME) value? Is it possible to make that UNIQUE?

Comment: @Ebadly.Decipher: You can create `UNIQUE` constraints on all of your columns, but I'd suggest to minimize if possible. Also, you can make only the `DT` column unique as well, or a combination of `DT` columns with other columns.

Comment: The code you have provided for me, is that supposed to be used before or after insertion? Or during?

Comment: @Ebadly.Decipher: Execute it in your database only once. This will alter your table schema and add that constraint in your table. This is not part of this or any INSERT/SELECT query, it's a DDL manipulation, so should be done only once.

Comment: I am bit of a newbie, so excuse me if I do sound like one. But is there a way of doing that by writing it in PHP?

Comment: @Ebadly.Decipher: Yes, there is. Before the insertion, select from your database using the same values that you are trying to insert. Count the number of rows returned. If it is greater than zero, then you already have those values in the database, so don't insert them again. But this style is strongly discouraged.